# Improving performance of multiple FETCH requests in Javascript

Tags: javascript, php, performance, fetch-api

I'm trying to improve the performance of a website which uses multiple (>20) Javascript FETCH requests to fetch data from a PHP server. The problem is that most of the requests stall for some time before they are sent to the server.

I've read on the web that Google Chrome, which I'm using for accessing the website,  only supports up to six concurrent TCP connections to the same server. I guess every FETCH request establishes a new TCP connection and that's why only six of them can be processed concurrently.

[image: Chrome Network Monitor]

Obviously, it comes to mind that sending all requests over the same connection could solve the performance issue, but I couldn't find a solution for that.

This is part of my js-code:

```
draw_table(pageID, 28, fullUrls);

function draw_table(pageID, chartID, fullUrls) {
    fetch(fullUrls[chartID]).then(function (response) {
        response.json().then(function (json) {
            let data = new google.visualization.DataTable(json);
            let table = new google.visualization.Table(document.getElementById(`table_div_${graphs[chartID]}`));
            table.draw(data, { height: '100%' });
        })
    }).catch(function(error) {
            console.error('Error:', error);
        })
}
```

This is part of my serverside code:

```
if ($_GET['chart'] == $charts_sub[12]) {

    $total = mysqli_query($con, $sql_sub[44]);

    $rows = array();
    $table = array();

    $table['cols'] = array(
        array('label' => 'Method','type' => 'string'),
        array('label' => '#Requests','type' => 'number'),
    );

    $row1 = mysqli_fetch_row($total);
    $sub_array = array();
    $sub_array[] = array("v" => 'Total Packets');
    $sub_array[] = array("v" => $row1[0]);
    $rows[] =  array("c" => $sub_array);

    $table['rows'] = $rows;
    echo json_encode($table);
    mysqli_free_result($list);
}
```

I hope someone can help me. Thank you.

Comment: What does the server do there? 3 seconds for a few bytes is very slow.

Comment: Use [HTTP/2](https://http2.github.io/). It allows for pipelining and multiplexing of requests.

Comment: The server runs a mysql server and returns data from the database in JSON format to the Client.

Comment: This is a serverside problem. 1) the server is way to slow in general 2) if you want to only make one request that has to be supported by the server, so please add your serverside code ...

Comment: I've added some serverside code. I think the server responding slowly may be caused by SQL queries or table structures not fully optimized.

Comment: @HereticMonkey Thank you, I'll have a look into it!

Comment: If your PHP environment has session autostart turned on, you'll see significant improvements if you add `session_write_close();` at the top of your PHP code. This will stop the requests having to wait until the previous one has finished processing. Worth a try.

Comment: @rjdown Unfortunately, this doesn't seem to work/bring any performance benefits.

Answer (score 0):

You should combine some request into a request and server can handle multiple tasks at the same time. For example, in the URL you can send 10 `chartIDs` in a request after server will handle and response result is a list data of 10 charts.